# Define parameter for module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, module.exports

I have the following code implementation

**module.exports.post_get_follower = async (req, res)** => {

```
Post.find({ 'email': res.locals.user.email })
    .then(posts => {
        res.json(posts);
    });
}
```

And

```
router.get('/post-user-follower', postController.post_get_follower);
```

And I call it with the following implementations

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/person/' + hiddenElement)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(pers => {
        pers.persons.forEach(person => {

            const mail = person.email;

            fetch('/post-user-follower')
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(posts => {
              posts.reverse();
              posts.forEach(post => {

              const div = document.createElement('div');

              const header = document.createElement('h3');
              header.textContent = post.email;

              const text = document.createElement('p');
              text.textContent = post.text;

              const date = document.createElement('small');
              date.textContent = new Date(post.createdAt);
              
              const placeholder = document.createElement('p');
              placeholder.innerHTML = '<br>'; 

              div.appendChild(header);
              div.appendChild(text);
              div.appendChild(date);
              div.appendChild(placeholder);

              postsElement.appendChild(div);
              });
            });

        });
  });
```

How can I define a parameter in the module.exports and use it like " `email`: parameter " (instead of `res.locals.user.email`) in my `module.exports` and how can I call it with `const mail` in my second implementation?

Comment: You don't want to define a parameter to the exported function. You want to define a HTTP API parameter. So decide how you want to pass the email (in the url path, in the query part of the url, in a header, in the body), and then implement that.